# How to use mySql DB from C# on shared hosting?

Tags: mysql

i bought a web domain with some web space. They support only mySQL DB, how do i access the my SQL DB on my asp.net application? is there is way to access it through .net base classes without installing third party drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference [MySQL .net connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) .dll which will be placed in your bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

The standard [Conector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net.html) should work.  It's pure C# and communicates with MySQL over sockets.  If that isnt supported you should talk to your host about how to get it working.